# Why is a temporary std::lock_guard object immediately unlocked?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread, temporary-objects, stdmutex

I'm learning about `std::mutex`, `std::thread` and I am surprised at the different behavior of 2 pieces of code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mtx;

void foo(int k)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{ mtx };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << "This is a test!" << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The test " << k << " has been finished." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(foo, 1);
    std::thread t2(foo, 2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is sequential. But if I donot name variable `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`, the output is **unordered**

```
void foo(int k)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> { mtx }; // just erase the name of variable
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << "This is a test!" << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The test " << k << " has been finished." << std::endl;
}
```

It seems like `std::lock_guard` is no use in 2nd case, Why?

Comment: Slightly OT: I commend your use of braces for initializing `std::lock_guard` because I once wrote a bug as following: `using namespace std; /*...*/ mutex mutex_; /*...*/ lock_guard<mutex> lock(mutex);` – note the missing underscore and that this is therefore a (useless) function declaration according to the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)… This cannot happen when using braces.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This declaration

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> { mtx };
```

doesn't bind the created object to a name, it's a temporary variable that exists only for this particular statement. Opposed to that, a variable that has a name and is created on the stack lives until the end of the scope in which it's created.

In [this CppCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkgszkPnV8g) (starting at [31:42](https://youtu.be/lkgszkPnV8g?t=31m42s)), the presenter lists the creation of temporary `std::lock_guard` instances not bound to a local variable as a common bug in the Facebook code base.

Comment: A bit of nit picking: It's more precise to say "complete statement" than "line of code". Newlines are treated the same as any other whitespace in C(++), but for a few minor exceptions like ending a preprocessor directive (if not escaped) or a `//` comment etc.

Comment: To be fair, the bug at Facebook is a bit different: Instead of creating a temporary variable, it is creating a new variable :)