# How do you give the rvalue generated by a constructor the lifetime of an lvalue?

Tags: c++

```
while(model.condition) {
    auto data = yield_data();
    auto _= manipulate(model, data);
    model.get_info(args);
}
```

I have an RAII object of type `manipulate`, whose destructor undoes the mutation it causes when it falls out of scope, much like `std::lock_guard`. The problem is that the user has to type `auto _=` or the destructor will get called before `model.get_info()`; I don't like that the user has to type `auto _=`. Why would a user think to create an object that is never used?

My first idea was to make the constructor `[[nodiscard]]`; but constructors have no return values. Is there a way to tell the compiler that manipulate rvalues should have lvalue lifetimes?

Comment: You can use static code-analysis tools to guard against this kind of mistake, like clang-tidy.

Comment: After `register` was removed in C++17, a proposal came out to re-purpose it for prolonging the life of temporaries. I don't know what's the state of [p0577](https://wg21.link/p0577) today, but assuming the author keeps pursuing it, maybe there will be a better way in the future. Who knows.

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2012/05/when-is-a-scoped-lock-not-a-scoped-lock/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to extend the lifetime of an rvalue beyond the full-expression it appears in without binding it to some variable. So, unfortunately, you will have to *somehow* turn your rvalue into an lvalue, or move the actual work into a scope that does not outlive the rvalue.

One way to achieve the latter is to use a callback as demonstrated in the other answers here.

Alternatively, thanks to guaranteed copy elision, you could turn your `manipulate()` into a function instead of calling the constructor directly. This would at least allow you to take advantage of the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute, for example:

```
[[nodiscard]] manipulate begin_transaction(const Model& model, const Data& data)
{
    return { model, data };
}

while(model.condition)
{
    auto data = yield_data();
    auto guard = begin_transaction(model, data);
    model.get_info(args);
}
```

[try it out here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%0A%0Astruct+manipulate%0A%7B%0A++++manipulate(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%7D%0A++++manipulate(const+manipulate%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A++++manipulate(manipulate%26%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A++++manipulate%26+operator+%3D(const+manipulate%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A++++manipulate%26+operator+%3D(manipulate%26%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%5B%5Bnodiscard%5D%5D+manipulate+begin_transaction(int+a,+int+b)%0A%7B%0A++++return+%7B+a,+b+%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+test()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+guard+%3D+begin_transaction(42,+23)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher there is no way to extend the lifetime of an rvalue beyond its full-expression without binding it to some variable. The way I understood the question is that OP was lamenting the fact that he cannot even use `[[nodiscard]]`, which the function approach presented above would allow. I edited the answer to make this more clear…

Answer (score 2):

It's an unsolved problem for `std::lock_guard` as well, if you forget to give it a name, you get a bug.

Some tricks in here: [How to avoid C++ anonymous objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189742/how-to-avoid-c-anonymous-objects)

A talk about this and other pitfalls linked here: [Different behavior when `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` object has no name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963131/different-behavior-when-stdlock-guardstdmutex-object-has-no-name)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this. No other choice.

A good example of this being indeed painful is NAG Automatic Differentiation DCO library, where you have to add lots of `const auto&` to your code because they rely on the destruction order to create a graph (RAII, just like you rely on this).

So would say, even use `const auto& _` so that you ensure that `_` doesn't get changed if this is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Require the user to tell the `manipulate` ctor what code they want to run. So change it to take a callable as argument and call it:

```
manipulate(model, data, [&model, &args] {
    model.get_info(args);
});
```